# Fill up RecyclerView inside of another RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm new with RecyclerView. I have created a RecyclerView and this RecycerView shows me all the orders someone has. When someone clicks a row in the RecyclerView (when someone clicks an order), a pop up should be shown where details of the orders are  being shown. The pop up works, but the RecyclerView isn't filled up, because the RecyclerView cannot be recognised (classic NullPointerException :D). My question is - how can I fill up the RecylerView inside of the Adapter. You can see my code below.

[Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoNpX.png)

I created a "picture" of how it should look like. The RecyclerView is shown with an order. When I click on a certain order, a pop up should show with the detailed order.

Thank you very much in advance! Wish you a good day/evening.

**Adapter what I want inside**

```
public class UserBestellAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Bestellung> bestellung;
    Context mContext;
    Dialog epicDialog;
    UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<ModelOverviewOrder> orderList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public UserBestellAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bestellung> list) {
        mContext = context;
        bestellung = list;
        epicDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_bestell, parent, false);
         viewHolder = new UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder(view);


        return viewHolder;
    }
    @NonNull

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserBestellAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      //Gesamtpreis:   holder.item_betrag.setText(String.valueOf(bestellung.get(position).getBetrag()));
      // Datum:   holder.item_datum.setText(bestellung.get(position).getDatum());
        holder.item_items.setText(bestellung.get(position).getProdukte());
        //holder.item_code.setText(bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer());
        String bestellid =bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer() + "";
        holder.item_code.setText(bestellid);
        holder.item_betrag.setText(Double.toString(bestellung.get(position).getSumme()));
        holder.item_datum.setText(bestellung.get(position).getDatum());


        holder.layout_user_bestellung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_order_scroll);

                orderList = new ArrayList<>();
                orderList.add(new ModelOverviewOrder("Toast", "5", "6.0"));


                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager = layoutManager;
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);

                OrderOverviewAdapter adapter = new OrderOverviewAdapter(mContext, orderList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                TextView order_overview_number = view.findViewById(R.id.order_overview_number);
                System.out.println("------>" + order_overview_number);
                epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_popup_order_overview);
                epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                Button btn_order_overview_finish = (Button) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_order_overview_finish);
                //System.out.println(bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer());
                getBestellung(bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer());
                btn_order_overview_finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        epicDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });
                epicDialog.show();


            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount()  {
        return bestellung.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView item_items, item_betrag, item_datum, item_code;
        private ConstraintLayout layout_user_bestellung;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            item_items = itemView.findViewById(R.id.items);
            item_betrag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.betrag);
            item_datum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datum);
            item_code = itemView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            layout_user_bestellung = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_user_bestellung);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class OrderOverviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderOverviewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ModelOverviewOrder> mlist;

    OrderOverviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelOverviewOrder> list) {
        mContext = context;
        mlist = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_popup_order_overview_adapter, parent, false);

        OrderOverviewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new OrderOverviewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextView artikel = holder.item_artikel;
        TextView preis = holder.item_preis;
        TextView anzahl = holder.item_anzahl;

        ModelOverviewOrder artikelItem = mlist.get(position);

        artikel.setText(artikelItem.getArtikel());
        preis.setText(artikelItem.getPreis());
        anzahl.setText(artikelItem.getAnzahl());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView item_preis, item_anzahl, item_artikel;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            item_preis = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_overview_preis);
            item_anzahl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_overview_anzahl);
            item_artikel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_overview_artikel);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_overview_artikel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Artikel"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_overview_anzahl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anzahl"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_overview_preis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preis" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**Popup XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:text="Bestellübersicht"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_overview_number"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Produkt"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Anzahl"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Preis"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="true"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_order_scroll"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
                    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


                </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="128dp"
                    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                    app:lottie_loop="true"
                    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/walkingburger" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_order_overview_finish"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_order_checkout"
                    android:backgroundTint="#9BC3BF"
                    android:elevation="16dp"
                    android:text="FERTIG"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.777" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Model Class**

```
public class ModelOverviewOrder {
    private String artikel, anzahl, preis;

    public ModelOverviewOrder(String artikel, String anzahl, String preis) {
        this.artikel = artikel;
        this.anzahl = anzahl;
        this.preis = preis;
    }

    public String getArtikel() {
        return artikel;
    }

    public void setArtikel(String artikel) {
        this.artikel = artikel;
    }

    public String getAnzahl() {
        return anzahl;
    }

    public void setAnzahl(String anzahl) {
        this.anzahl = anzahl;
    }

    public String getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public void setPreis(String preis) {
        this.preis = preis;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the pop up dialog you want to show must contain (inflate) the second recyclerView and because it a bit complicated UI/UX i suggest you should make your popup a custom view

Example : https://medium.com/@makkenasrinivasarao1/android-custom-dialog-with-list-of-items-ba1ab0e78e16

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
The PopUp works fine. Do I still need this inflate? And how do I display the ReyclerView? Do you have an idea ...? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the link i post above is the best way to show recylerView in dialog, you just need post the activity and adapter to dialog via constructor because the dialog already have recycler view in xml file.

Comment: Phan I appreciate your answers. Unfortunately I don't know. How I could the second inside of the dialog.

Comment: The dialog use a separate xml file for layout, in that xml file you already defined a recycler view by <RecyclerView> tag, all you need is set adapter for it. Not sure what is your issue.